# Counting prefixes from a csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Is there a way to make this python system count the prefixes in the array? I keep getting a prefixcount result of 0

Any help would be appreciated :)

The code I have is below

```
file = input("What is the csv file's name?")+".csv"
openfile = open(file)
text = sorted(openfile)
print("Sorted list")
print(text)
dictfile = open("DICT.txt")

prefix = ['de', 'dys', 'fore', 'wh']

prefixcount = 0
for word in text:
    for i in range(0, len(prefix)):
        if word>prefix[i]:
         break
        if word[0:len(prefix[i])] == prefix[i]:
             prefixcount+=1
             break
print(prefixcount)
```

Comment: What are you trying to test with `word>prefix[i]`?

Comment: If the word is longer than the prefix it should skip it

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because: 1. `word>prefix[i]` is comparing lexicographically, not by length; and 2. isn't the whole point of a prefix that it's shorter than the word it's in? Coudl you give some examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: if it the word for example is "it" then a prefix of "dys" would be longer, so the system would skip it

Comment: That's the opposite of what you're trying to test, you want `len(word) < len(prefix[i])` (i.e. the word is shorter than the prefix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, when you meet a condition where you want to skip an iteration, use `continue` - `break` ends the loop entirely.

Secondly, `word>prefix[i]` does not do what you want; it compares the strings lexicographically (see e.g. [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types)), and you really want to know `len(word) < len(prefix[i])`.

I think what you want is:

```
prefixcount = 0
for word in text:
    for pref in prefix:
        if word.startswith(pref):
            prefixcount += 1
```